# Rewriting URL with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite urls with nginx.

Samples:

```
/something.php (not regular file) -> /index.php?site=something
/somthingelse.php (regular file) -> /somethingelse.php
```

My current rules doesn't work:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rules;
}

location @rules {
    rewrite ^/([a-z]*)\.php$ /index.php?s=$1;
}
```

Comment: Regular file meaning "existing" and non-regular as "not existing"? Like a virtual file location? I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: I guess you have something like `location \.php$`

Comment: @AlexeyTen: yes i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/something.php` url is catched by `location ~ \.php$`, so you need rewrite it there.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @rules;
    # usual php stuff
    ...;
}

location @rules {
    rewrite ^/([a-z]*)\.php$ /index.php?s=$1 last;
    return 404;
}
```

For existing file `/somefile.php` it will be processed by PHP as usual.

For non-existent `/other.php` it will be internally redirected to `@rules` where it will be rewritten to `/index.php?s=other` and gets again into `location ~ \.php` and finally processed by PHP.

And for non-existent `/w31rd.php`  (where `w31rd` doesn't match `[a-z]*` regexp) you will get `404 Not Found` error page.